# Problems getting DHCP connection to router after recent 18.04 update

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dhcp

Since the last Ubuntu 18.04 update (I use the automatic software updater) some time in the last week the ethernet connection to my router (Telekom Speedport Smart 3) isn't working any more.

I checked the cable, using it from another OS thats installed on the same box works without a problem.

My router logs shows failed DHCP connection attempts when I try to connect from Ubuntu 18.04, unfortunately not much more details.

Here's the logs from the NetworkManager when I try to connect:

```
$ journalctl -u NetworkManager
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8154] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (aae30bcd-f48c-3355-b8ea-0f85b41ceda7)
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8155] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="aae30bcd-f48c-3355-b8ea-0f85b41ceda7" name="Wired connection 1" pid=14866 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8159] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8162] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8168] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8179] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8183] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8206] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 22206
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.102 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x314975af)
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1 (xid=0xaf754931)
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8588] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> expire
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800379.8616] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed expire -> unknown
Sep 18 11:52:59 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:53:01 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800381.6610] dhcp6 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 18 11:53:01 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800381.6627] dhcp6 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 22223
Sep 18 11:53:02 Oland dhclient[22223]: XMT: Info-Request on enp3s0, interval 1090ms.
Sep 18 11:53:02 Oland dhclient[22223]: RCV: Reply message on enp3s0 from fe80::1.
Sep 18 11:53:02 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800382.0790] dhcp6 (enp3s0):   nameserver 'fe80::1'
Sep 18 11:53:02 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800382.0791] dhcp6 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Sep 18 11:53:02 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800382.0807] dhcp6 (enp3s0): client pid 22223 exited with status 0
Sep 18 11:53:02 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800382.0807] dhcp6 (enp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Sep 18 11:53:02 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:53:03 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800383.1215] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 18 11:53:03 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800383.1227] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 18 11:53:03 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800383.1235] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 18 11:53:03 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800383.1238] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 18 11:53:03 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800383.1292] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Sep 18 11:53:03 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800383.1293] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Sep 18 11:53:03 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800383.1298] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 18 11:53:08 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:53:14 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:53:23 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:53:33 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800413.6583] connectivity: (enp3s0) timed out
Sep 18 11:53:36 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:53:47 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:54:07 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:54:18 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:54:29 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:54:40 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:54:52 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:54:57 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800497.6581] connectivity: (enp3s0) timed out
Sep 18 11:55:05 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:55:15 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:55:34 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:55:44 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:55:51 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:56:07 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:56:23 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:56:34 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:56:46 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:56:59 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:57:15 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:57:30 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:57:51 Oland dhclient[22206]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x7178e0b)
Sep 18 11:58:00 Oland dhclient[22206]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Sep 18 11:58:00 Oland dhclient[22206]: Trying recorded lease 192.168.2.201
Sep 18 11:58:00 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800680.9260] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Sep 18 11:58:00 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800680.9583] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 22206
Sep 18 11:58:00 Oland NetworkManager[1325]: <info>  [1568800680.9584] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed timeout -> done
```

I briefly tried disabling Ipv6 on the wire connection settings but this didn't change anything, so I set it to "automatic" again.

Any ideas how to dig further?
Any known recent updates that might be connected to this?
I'd like to simply try to apply newer system updates to see if this fixes the issue but since I'm offline on that machine I don't know how to do that easily. How would one apply recent system updates on a machine that doesn't have connection?

Thanks for any pointers.